# Go regex, Negative Look Ahead alternative

Tags: regex, go

I am trying to implement the regex `(?<!\\{)\\[[a-zA-Z0-9_]+\\](?!\\})` with go regex.

Match value will be like `[ua]` and `[ua_enc]` and unmatched should be `{[ua]}` and `{[ua_enc]}`

As Negative lookahead is not supported in Go, what may be the alternative expression for this?

Comment: A workaround depends on what you want to achieve in the end, replace or extract text. You may most probably use [`(^|[^{])(\[\w+\])([^}]|$)`](https://regex101.com/r/sk3cwV/2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no alternative expression for this. Using plain `(?:[^{]|^)(...)(?:[^}]|$)` to capture the intended match and assert the previous and next characters are not braces will kind-of work: you will need to work with the first capture group instead of with the full match, and it will fail when there is only a single character between two matches (e.g. `[foo]_[bar]`). The best way, really, is to use `FindAllStringSubmatchIndex` and manually check the previous and next characters to make sure they are not braces outside of regexp.